# Make all instances of a word a hyperlink in OpenOffice

Tags: automation, openoffice, hyperlink

How can I make every instance of a word, a hyperlink to a file on my computer.

I have managed to do it with one instance of the word, but repeating this be time consuming so I am hoping that the program itself can do it.

I also would like to use the %windir% and %userprofile% system variables in the file.

Here is what I tried:

%windir%\system32\shell32.dll

However this gets replaced (and fails) by Openoffice to look like this:

"%25windir%25\system32\shell32.dll"

If I add double quotes, openoffice adds another pair to the path and that also makes windows not find the file.

I have looked in edit > File & Replace but dont see any option to replace all instalces of a word with a hyperlink to a file whilst keeping the word the same.

Comment: I am unaware of any mechanism in OpenOffice to do this sort of editing, so what I'd do is to save as HTML, then use a good text editor (such as NotePad++) for the global edits. It can then be re-opened in OpenOffice for further editing, or saving in whatever format is required. However, I doubt if OO will handle environment variables, even if prefixed by `file://`.

Comment: Are you asking about Writer or Calc?

Answer (score 0):

First, select the existing link that you created and copy it.  Then, run this macro, which will find all occurrences of "TheWordToLink" and paste the link in those places.

```vb
Sub PasteHyperlinks
    Dim vDescriptor, vFound, oVC
    Dim document, dispatcher
    oVC = ThisComponent.CurrentController.ViewCursor
    document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
    dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
    vDescriptor = ThisComponent.createSearchDescriptor()
    With vDescriptor
        .SearchString = "TheWordToLink"
        .SearchWords = True
        .SearchCaseSensitive = False
    End With
    vFound = ThisComponent.findFirst(vDescriptor)
    Do While Not IsNull(vFound)
        oVC.gotoRange(vFound, False)
        dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Paste", "", 0, Array())
        vFound = ThisComponent.findNext( vFound.End, vDescriptor)
    Loop
End Sub
```

*Search and replace code was taken from section 7.14 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php).*

As far as environment variables, that requires a more difficult solution.  That is, call a macro from the link, and then the macro will perform the system call to the file.  If you are using Basic:

1. See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=53609 for how make a hyperlink call a macro.
2. See [Creating automatic links in OpenOffice](https://superuser.com/questions/342102/creating-automatic-links-in-openoffice) for code that can find and create the hyperlinks.
3. See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=25047 for a macro that uses an environment variable in a path.
4. See https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=7918 for system calls.